# How can I make dynamic content boxes unique for each customer?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, dynamic

I'm not a programmer but I'm building a brief for my site and would appreciate your help.
I sell services on WordPress, and the products of the service must be uploaded to the site on a dedicated and unique page for each user who purchased the service.
I find it hard to do something like that.
The page should include a number of dynamic content cells, and there should be some way that the information will be specific to the logged in user, and if he has not purchased the service or is not yet ready, it will display something accordingly.

I'm looking for a guide or a brief or an explanation for this process.

TIA.

Comment: So if i understand correctly you are selling services (the actual product) and after that you want to assign end product unique to every client. What kind of product we are talking here ? Digital physical ? What data should hold. In most cases creating relationship between the order , customer and product will be enough. To visualise it you need to create page template for example and just do your logic there.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.